# ckeditor new styles not working (laravel 5)

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, styles

I have modified the file styles.js with an example of styles:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'estilos', [
// Block-level styles
{ name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
{ name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },

// Inline styles
{ name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },
{ name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-

color': 'Yellow' } }
] );
```

And in config.js I added the line: **config.stylesSet = 'estilos';**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.stylesSet = 'estilos';

config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

But this doesn't work. The styles option in the view is disabled:
[image: Styles option view]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a working demo? including the init function for ckedit etc.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas Moors, I have solved it. I put the answer bellow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved it :)
You must to put the line **config.stylesSet = 'estilos'** after **config.toolbarGroups**

I hope that it would be useful to someone.